# How to force Apache Tomcat not to reuse a thread from the thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, tomcat, tomcat6

We've got a normal-ish server stack including BlazeDS, Tomcat and Hibernate.

We'd like to arrange things such that if certain errors (especially AssertionError) are thrown, the current thread is considered to be in an unknown state and won't be used for further HTTP requests. (Partly because we're storing some things, such as Hibernate transaction session, in thread-local storage. Now, we can catch throwables and make sure to roll back transactions and rethrow, but there's no guarantee about what other code may have left who knows what in the thread-local storage.)

Tomcat with the default thread pool behavior reuses threads. We tried specifying our own executor, which seems to be the most specific method of changing its thread pool behavior, but it doesn't always call Executor.execute() with a new task for each request. (Most likely it reuses the same execution context for all requests in the same HTTP connection.)

One option is to disable keepalive, so that there's only one request per HTTP connection, but that's ugly.

Anyway, I'd like to know. Is there a way to tell Tomcat not to reuse a thread, or to kill or exit the thread so that Tomcat is forced to create a new one?

(From the Tomcat source, it appears Tomcat will close the connection and abandon the task/thread after sending a HTTP 500 response, but I don't know how to get BlazeDS to generate a 500 response; that's another angle I'd like to know more about.)

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest simply getting rid of your use of thread-local storage, or at least coming up with a method to clear the thread-local storage when a request first enters the pipeline (with a [`<filter>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) in web.xml, for example).

Having to reconfigure something basic about Tomcat to get it to work with your app points to a code smell.

Comment: You can say that about the smell; OTOH one could also argue that this is something Tomcat should be doing anyway (by default, uncaught exceptions and errors including AssertionError seem to be pretty much dropped on the floor, unless I'm missing something -- we already had to write a filter to log the existence of said throwables). Anyway this isn't about getting Tomcat to work with our app, or anything peculiar our app is doing, I think -- it works, it just keeps going with a little too much gusto after exceptions, and I want to make sure all bases are covered.

Comment: And yeah, our filter could clean up after stale thread-local state it knows about, or any code we write that puts stuff in thread-local state can use try/catch/finally to make sure it gets cleaned up, but. Something else somewhere else in the system could also forget to do this. I'm just trying to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: One more thought. It's pretty straightforward to get Tomcat to abandon a thread by generating a 500 response, so wanting to do this doesn't seem like an abuse of the Tomcat design. Really, it's the combination of Tomcat+BlazeDS+Hibernate that makes this both desirable and difficult.